# JQuery slidetoggle nested lists closing open list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple nested list like so:

```html
<ul class='main'>
  <li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 1</a>
    <ul class='sub'>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-1</a>
        <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-2</a>
          <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-3</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 2</a>
      <ul class='sub'>
        <li><a href='#'>Sub 2-1</a>
          <li><a href='#'>Sub 2-2</a>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-3</a>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 3</a>
        <ul class='sub'>
          <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-1</a>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a>
              <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a>
        </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$( ".mainlink" ).click(function() { 
    var child = $(this).children('.sub');
    var rest = $('.sub:visible').not(child);     
    child.slideToggle();
    rest.slideUp();    
});
```

Clicking `.mainlink` should open its child list `.sub` and close all other child lists that are open. This part is working as expected but clicking on `.mainlink` with the open `.sub` closes `.sub` and opens it immediately after instead of keeping it closed until the next click happens.

The problem is probably easy to solve, but I'm obviously not able to find the right approach. Thanks for your help.

Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".mainlink > a" ).click(function() { 
        $('.main .sub').not($(this)).slideUp();
        var child = $(this).parent().children('.sub');
        if(!child.is(":visible")){
            child.slideDown();      
        }    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='main'>
<li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 1</a>
<ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 1-1</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 1-2</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 1-3</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 2</a>
<ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 2-1</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 2-2</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 3-3</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='mainlink'><a href='#'>Main 3</a>
<ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 3-1</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a>
<li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but no luck: Clicking the open menu clodes it and opens it immediately after.

Comment: Bingo! Now everything is doing very well! Thanks a lot, Saeed.

Answer (score 0):

Close all `.sub` then open the `.sub` that was selected by user

### Demo

```js
$(".mainlink a").on('click', function() {
  var subMenu = $(this).next('.sub');
  $('.sub').slideUp();
  if (subMenu.is(':visible')) {
    subMenu.slideUp();
  } else {
    subMenu.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class='main'>
  <li class='mainlink'>
    <a href='#'>Main 1</a>
    <ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='mainlink'>
    <a href='#'>Main 2</a>
    <ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='mainlink'>
    <a href='#'>Main 3</a>
    <ul class='sub' style='display:none'>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sub 3-2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi zerOOne, thanks for your suggestion, your code is working fine too. As I’ve already marked Saeed answer as the right one I can only give a vote. Edit: Sadly I cannot  even vote, as my reputation is too low. Strange rules, sometimes.

Comment: That's fine @Ralf, thank you for being so considerate. Happy coding. 